# update mysql column using random number lower then column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a mysql table with multiple rows, having columns : column1, column2 with different values.
I want to do something like this for each row:

```
$sql    = "UPDATE table SET column2 = rand(0,(column1/3000))";
```

Is this possible, or there is another way to do that? TY!

EDIT.
Even with column1/3000 enclosed by parentheses or not, it gives me the error:

```
Error: UPDATE table SET column2 = rand(0,(column1/3000))
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'rand'
```

Comment: Did you try?  Did you get logs, errors, ...?

Comment: updated my post. Thanks for notice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the RAND() function as:

`$sql = "UPDATE table SET column2 = (column1/3000)*RAND()";`

The above will update `column2` to a number between `0` and `column1/3000`.
In case `column2` is of `int` type, the results will be rounded to the nearest integer.

On the RAND() function, see for example: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-rand-function.php

Comment: now...i have another question, but i am afraid to open another topic...